# Why is there still a D next to my launchScreen.storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, git, xcode-storyboard

I accidentally trashed the folder containing all my swift and storyboard files. I moved the folder back to its original position and everything's fine (all files have ?, M, or A next to it), except  launchScreen.storyboard has a D (meaning ready for deletion) next to it.
[image]

I closed and reopened Xcode and I still see the D next to launchScreen.storyboard. The Full file path in its identity inspector looks correct to me. Is this just an Xcode 8 glitch? If I push my project to git, will the file be deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The D means that the file is marked for deletion in your repository (Git, by default.)

(The instructions below assume you're using Git as your source control system, which is the default. If you're using SVN instead, let us know.)

Open a terminal window. Type "cd " (with a space) and then drag your top-level project folder (the one that contains the project file) into the terminal window. That should create a change directory command that's formatted correctly even if some of your directories contain spaces.

Press enter. The terminal should now be pointing to your project directory.

Type "git status" and hit enter.

It will probably show your file "launchScreen.storyboard" as deleted.

If so, type `git add <path_to_file>` where you replace `<path_to_file>` with a partial path to the file in question (which may be in a subdirectory of your project folder.)

Once you've done that, commit your project and the file should be back in your repository.

As @Scriptable said in their answer, you could also type `git add .`, but that would add **EVERY** untracked file in your project folder to your git repository that's not excluded by your .gitignore file, which you may not want to do.

Answer (score 0):

When you use git, xCode adds some letters next to the file. Examples:

- D - deleted
- A - added
- M - modified

Comment: But why does it say D? Since I re-added the deleted file back to its original position, shouldn't it say A or ? (item not under version control) like the other deleted-but-then-re-added files in my project?

Comment: If you didn't commit after deletion, it should say D. When you add the same file xCode may get confused. Just delete it commit and add, or discard changes to this file.

Answer (score 0):

This does seem to indicate its been removed from GIT, when it comes to committing it should give you an option to add it again by checking the checkbox next to the file.

You could also run `git add .` from in a terminal window if your in the projects directory.

Try running `git status` from the same place in the terminal and it should show any files that have been modified, added or deleted.